# Returning in multiprocessing - Python

Tags: python, queue, return, multiprocessing

I'm working on a code for visualization. First of all, I have to generate a large number of images. So, I though about parallelize this process. Until now, I have this code:

```
class ImageData(object):

    def __init__(self, width, height, range_min=-1, range_max=1):
        """
        The ImageData constructor
        """
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        #The values range each pixel can assume
        self.range_min = range_min
        self.range_max = range_max
        self.data = []
        for i in range(width):
            self.data.append([0] * height)

    def shepard_interpolation(self, queue, seeds=10):
        """
        Perform a Shepard shepard_interpolation
        :param queue
        :param seeds
        """
        points = []
        f = []
        for s in range(seeds):
            # Generate a pixel position
            pos_x = random.randrange(self.width)
            pos_y = random.randrange(self.height)

            # Save the f(x,y) data
            x = Utils.translate_range(pos_x, 0, self.width, self.range_min, self.range_max)
            y = Utils.translate_range(pos_y, 0, self.height, self.range_min, self.range_max)
            z = Utils.function(x, y)
            points.append([x, y])
            f.append(z)

        for i in range(self.width):
            xt = (Utils.translate_range(i, 0, self.width, self.range_min, self.range_max))
            for j in range(self.height):
                yt = (Utils.translate_range(j, 0, self.height, self.range_min, self.range_max))
                self.data[i][j] = Utils.shepard_euclidian(points, f, [xt, yt], 3)
        queue.put(self)

class Utils:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def shepard_euclidian(x, z, p, u):
        n = len(x)
        d = [0.0] * n
        for i in range(n-1):
            pi = x[i]
            d[i] = math.pow(math.hypot(pi[0]-p[0], pi[1]-p[1]), u)
        w = [0.0] * n
        sw = 0.0
        for i in range(n-1):
            w[i] = 1.0
            for k in range(n-1):
                if i != k:
                    w[i] *= d[k]
            sw += w[i]
        for i in range(len(w)-1):
            if sw != 0.0:
                w[i] /= sw
            else:
                w[i] = 0.0
        c = 0.0
        for i in range(n):
            c += (w[i] * z[i])
        return c

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    processes = [Process(target=ImageData.shepard_interpolation, args=(ImageData(50, 50), q,))    for _ in range(2)]
    for process in processes:

    process.start()
    for process in processes:
        print "Trying to join"
        process.join()
        if hasattr(os, 'getppid'):  # only available on Unix
            print process.pid, 'joining', os.getppid()
    print "Finish"
```

The problem is cause some of my process never ends. I found that if I comment the line `queue.put(self)`, in `queue.put(self)`, all process finish, but I don't receive any return. But if I uncommented this line, I receive the print **Trying to join**, but it never ends. I really don't know what is the problem. I though about process trying to write in the queue at the same time, but I discovered that this is already managed by it. I don't have any clue about what is the problem.

Any help would be very appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably overflowing the queue. Multiprocessing queues are based on FIFOs, and have a fixed buffer size. You should try to queue.get() the data in the main routine before you join the processes.

shameless plug: consider using my [vimap](https://github.com/gatoatigrado/vimap) library. it works around a lot of multiprocessing weirdness.

Comment: Yeah, I did this yesterday and it worked, but I didn't found why this make sense. Now I know! Thank you!

Comment: PS: I'll take a look at this library. (: